# TinyMCE 'mceImage' execCommand returns false

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

In Chrome 66 and using the `mobile` theme, the `mceImage` command returns false.  What I'm expecting that it'll open the image dialog of the `image` plugin.

Doesn't work and returns false:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.editorCommands.execCommand('mceImage');
```

Works and returns true:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.editorCommands.execCommand('bold');
```

Anybody knows why?  And is there also a different way to trigger the image upload dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://www.tinymce.com/docs/mobile/#configuringtheplugins):

> The plugins supported by mobile are currently limited to the `autosave`,
>   `autolink` and `lists` plugins. This is by design. We are in the early
>   release cycle and want to hear from our developer community about
>   which plugins should be mobile optimized.

So I would expect that trying to trigger the image dialog on mobile would not work as that plugin does not appear to be supported on the mobile theme.

Comment: You're right; I did read that too... such a shame.  It's a good theme but very limited.  I had to hack the hell out of it to get it working the way I wanted it to.